# How to document webhooks in Swagger?

Tags: api, swagger, documentation, webhooks, swagger-editor

I'm building a set of APIs and webhooks. For the usual APIs, I have no problem writing the YAML file to document that in Swagger. However, I would like to also document the webhooks such as their request body payload and other information about them in the Swagger documentation.

How are webhooks or reversed API usually documented in Swagger?